# Converting Byte Array into short - strange results

Tags: c#

I am converting an 2 bytes long byte array into an short (Int16) and showing it via a messagebox.

```
MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(arr) + "\n" + BitConverter.ToInt16(arr, 0));
```

But the results are a bit strange. Here a few examples:

```
Array    Short   Correct Result
-------------------------------
00-60    24576            24576
AB-2A    10923            10923
55-55    21845            21845
00-80   -32768            32768
AB-AA   -21845            43691
55-D5   -10923            54613
```

Comment: Why are the results strange? Int16 cannot represent values from 32768 and up, only values from -32768 to +32767. You want UInt16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ToInt16`, which returns numbers from -32768 to 32767, so numbers out of range will be truncated or adjusted to fit the range. For numbers from 0 through 65535, which seems to be what you want, use `ToUInt16` instead:

```
MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(arr) + "\n" + BitConverter.ToUInt16(arr, 0));
```